# BroadcastReceiver is not receiving

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-intentservice

I am new to the Android API and I am trying to implement a scheduled process that reports back to the app.
So, I have the following code in my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AlarmManager almgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        IntentFilter statusIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("Report");
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.v("Receiver","Received!");
            }
        };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                receiver, statusIntentFilter);
        Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Background.class);
        almgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,mServiceIntent,0);
        almgr.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+1000, alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

And this is my `IntentService class`

```
public class Background extends IntentService {
    public Background(){super("Background");}
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(this.toString(),"Service called");
        Intent localIntent = new Intent("Report")
                .putExtra("Value","True");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
    }
}
```

The `IntentService` is receiving the initial `Intent` and the Log entry in the Background class is printed but the BroadcastReceiver is not receiving the `Report Intent`. It is not printing the "Receiver Received" Log.

Comment: Have you declare IntentService and Broadcast in maenifest files? you should read this tutorials http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: @RamchandraSingh Dynamic Receivers do not need to be listed in the manifest. And the OP states that the log print in the Service is happening, so it must already be listed in the manifest.

Comment: Not entirely sure. But for the Action, does that need to follow the same rules as Package Name in Android? Currently it is "Report", what happens if you change it to something like: "my.app.Report"?

Comment: @Cheesebaron It does not seem to work

Comment: I just tried displaying a Toast message instead and run it on actual hardware and the Toast showed! anyway, thank you guys.